# Trying to print a letter pyramid

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to print something like this:

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE
```

I tried this:

```
    e = 0
    for e in range(1,4):
    for f in range(e,0,-1):
        print "A B C D"
    print " "
```

But it's not working. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean *"not working"*? It appears to be incorrectly indented, for a start.

Answer (score 2):

```
abc = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
toprint=""
for x in range(len(abc)):
    toprint += abc[x]
    print(toprint)
```

that's how you can do what you want

or other version

```
abc = "ABCDE "

for x in range(1,len(abc)):
    print(abc[:x])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
letters='ABCDE'
for i in range (0,len(letters)+1):
    for j in range (0,i):
        sys.stdout.write(letters[j])
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```